# USB Headset - Works on Macbook, not on iMac

Tags: usb, headphones

I have a Rosewill USB headset (http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/f39e/) that works well with my Macbook Pro but not in my new iMac.

Macbook is a Mid 2010 running 10.9.1

When I plug it into my Macbook it works as expected, the sound settings change and everything works well.

I'm transitioning to an iMac (late 2013, running 10.9.1) and when I plug the headset in, it has never worked and only intermittently given me anything.

1) Some of the time the lights on the headset control will come on

2) Rarely the buttons will control the sound level, however the sound preference page won't show any valid input/output

I talked with the customer support at Rosewill and they said that it has happened before and the usb needs an updated driver, universal driver something along those lines that sounded good on the phone and I didn't write down well enough.

I spent some time googling and couldn't come up with anything.

The USB ports work at least for charging phones and for a logitech mouse.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Graham

Comment: Let me guess, you have a Fusion drive in that new iMac? There are a lot of issues with conflicts between USB audio and Apple's Fusion Drives. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5659615?start=0&amp;tstart=90

Comment: Does it show in your Sound panel?

Comment: Yeh that link describes is perfectly. I guess out of ignorance I didn't realize that they were different ports now.